# why the transaction failed?

Tags: spl-token, transactions, send-transaction, swap, raydium

so I send the transaction

```
    const buySign = await connection.sendTransaction(swapTx, [wallet], {
      skipPreflight: true,
      preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',
      maxRetries: 3
    })
```

I get a signature 5kDu6b5HRsCDEawpGGAJCbDgmArPsBCTdAsHqUGFykqWjBU6kAq3jjhPZVBzwpYdWs7ctYkmQjrn3Q3gLBCkErt1

but I don't see anything in the scanner. Why did my transaction fail? What should I pay attention to? I'm doing a swap on raydium

sometimes the transaction is successful, sometimes it is not
how to avoid this?

So. I added a serialized transaction. so you can see for yourself what's going on. Maybe this will help you understand why the transaction is not executed.

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector

```
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
```

even when I do a simulated transaction. I don't see any errors there. but for some reason, I still can’t make a transaction. Am I blocked on the blockchain? hahahahahaha, wtf

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the context why it wasn't sent to the network, but you can try serializing the Tx into base64 and running it with an inspector. This way you can see at least some information about the Tx and maybe decipher what is going wrong.

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector

You would need to do something like

```
const serializedTx = swapTx.serialize();
console.log(serializedTx.toString('base64'));
```

Then cut and paste the output into the simulator window in your browser.

Once the transaction is deserialized, the display will change to show information about the Tx. Make sure you don't miss the "simulate" button.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. I added a serialized transaction. but I didn't understand what the error was and why the transaction failed.

can you help?

Comment: The data you included looks like a successful transaction. So sometimes you get a successful transaction in the scanner and sometimes you get no transaction in the scanner? I wonder if it is not included in the block. Can you add a priority fee?

Comment: Yes everything is correct. sometimes the transaction succeeds. sometimes not. In recent days, I have had 1 successful transaction. 5 transactions not successful

Comment: const UNITPRICE = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 160_000
  })

  const UNITLIMIT = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
    units: 150_000
  })